# How to Find Time Difference for state change MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

My data is as below.

```
id  device      state   timestamp
250708  1004-3-007294   9   02/01/2019 9:20
250694  1004-3-007294   8   02/01/2019 9:31
250769  1004-3-007294   7   02/01/2019 10:04
250774  1004-3-007294   5   02/01/2019 10:13
250778  1004-3-007294   4   02/01/2019 10:20
250785  1004-3-007294   11  02/01/2019 10:27
250808  1004-3-007294   4   02/01/2019 10:29
250814  1004-3-007294   11  02/01/2019 10:36
250795  3091-5-007208   7   02/01/2019 10:39
250819  3091-5-007208   5   02/01/2019 10:42
250832  3091-5-007208   4   02/01/2019 10:58
250837  3091-5-007208   11  02/01/2019 11:02
250846  3091-5-007208   4   02/01/2019 11:13
```

I need to find time difference for all devices when 1st time device state changed from 5 to 4 as in my database device never will go again to state 5, but it will be changing state from 4 to 11, 11 to 4. Please help me to write query.

Comment: 1. Store dates as dates. 2. See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Incidentally, it seems a little odd (although not impossible) that ids aren't sequential with timetamps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JOIN for this. The following assumes that there is exactly one 5->4 transition so does not bother checking if it was the first transition:

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.id, TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, t1.timestamp,t2.timestamp) AS diff
FROM       t AS t1
INNER JOIN t AS t2 ON t2.device = t1.device AND t2.state = 4 AND t2.timestamp > t1.timestamp
LEFT  JOIN t AS tx ON t1.device = tx.device AND tx.timestamp > t1.timestamp AND tx.timestamp < t2.timestamp
WHERE t1.state = 5 AND tx.id IS NULL
```

The LEFT join in the above example ensures that only consecutive transition is matched (e.g. 250774 is joined to 250778 and 250808 but the latter is discarded).

[Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fb4b62f73385e99049235260e2a8943b)

Comment: LEFT  JOIN t AS tx
to which table here t is considered ? Facing error

Comment: @bilal you're supposed to replace t with actual table name. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fb4b62f73385e99049235260e2a8943b

Comment: Thanks salman, This query worked for me perfectly. Thank you much. I am feeling happy.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.Device, TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,B.t2,A.t1) as differenceintime
FROM
( SELECT device, MIN(timestamp) as t1
  FROM tableName
  WHERE state = 5
  GROUP BY device
) as A
INNER JOIN
( SELECT device, MIN(timestamp) as t2
  FROM tableName
  WHERE state = 4
  GROUP BY device
) as B

ON A.Device = B.Device
```

Comment: I am facing error for the declared alias A and B. If I use separate query then its being executed.

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Comment: checknow, i had forgotten FROM clause, corrected the answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select device,
       timestampdiff(second,
                     min(case when status = 4 then timestamp end),
                     max(case when status = 5 then timestamp end)
                    ) as diff_in_seconds
from t
group by device;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a later version of MySQL you can use the `LEAD` function to get the next state for each row

```
SELECT  *,
        LEAD(State) OVER(PARTITION BY device ORDER BY TimeStamp) AS NextState,
        LEAD(TimeStamp) OVER(PARTITION BY device ORDER BY TimeStamp) AS NextTimeStamp
FROM    t;
```

Which for one device will give:

```
id      device          state   timestamp               NextState       NextTimeStamp
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
250795  3091-5-007208   7       2019-02-01 10:39:00         5           2019-02-01 10:42:00
250819  3091-5-007208   5       2019-02-01 10:42:00         4           2019-02-01 10:58:00   <---
250832  3091-5-007208   4       2019-02-01 10:58:00         11          2019-02-01 11:02:00
250837  3091-5-007208   11      2019-02-01 11:02:00         4           2019-02-01 11:13:00
250846  3091-5-007208   4       2019-02-01 11:13:00        NULL                 NULL
```

This will allow you to identify when the state has changed from 5 to 4. You just need to put the above query into a subquery, and apply a where clause:

```
SELECT  t.device,
        t.TimeStamp AS ChangedToFive,
        t.NextTimeStamp AS ChangedFromFiveToFour
FROM    (   SELECT  *,
                    LEAD(State) OVER(PARTITION BY device ORDER BY TimeStamp) AS NextState,
                    LEAD(TimeStamp) OVER(PARTITION BY device ORDER BY TimeStamp) AS NextTimeStamp
            FROM    t
        ) AS t
WHERE   t.State = 5
AND     t.NextState = 4;
```

If you are using an older version that does not support the use of `LEAD`, then you will need to use co-related subqueries to replicate the functionality:

```
SELECT  t.device,
        t.TimeStamp AS ChangedToFive,
        t.NextTimeStamp AS ChangedFromFiveToFour
FROM    (   SELECT  *,
                    (   SELECT  TimeStamp
                        FROM    t AS t2
                        WHERE   t2.Device = t.Device
                        AND     t2.TimeStamp > t.TimeStamp
                        ORDER BY TimeStamp
                        LIMIT 1
                    ) AS NextTimeStamp
            FROM    t
            WHERE   t.State = 5
            AND     (   SELECT  State
                        FROM    t AS t2
                        WHERE   t2.Device = t.Device
                        AND     t2.TimeStamp > t.TimeStamp
                        ORDER BY TimeStamp
                        LIMIT 1
                    ) = 4 -- next state = 4 to satisfy changing from 5 to 4
        ) AS t;
```

**[Examples on DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=00f4498e73fe1f49b1444443d90b2b3c)**